# How to write a SQL patch that will take values from table A and insert as row within table B?

Tags: mysql, sql

I simply need to take every row within `photoProcess`table that has a storyId value (not 0 or null) and insert an entry into a new table called `photoProcessStory`.

Example of row within `photoProcess` table :

```
+----------------+----------+----------+
|  processId     | storyId  |  rating  |
+----------------+----------+----------+
|  111111111     | 322      |  1       |
|  111111112     | 333      |  1       |
|  111111113     | 0        |  1       |
+----------------+----------+----------+
```

The end resulting `photoProcessStory` table would look like this:

```
+-----+----------------+-------------------+
| id  |  processId     | storyId           |
+-----|----------------+-------------------+
| 1   |  111111111     | 322               |
| 2   |  111111112     | 333               |
+-----+----------------+-------------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have experience with joining tables and inserting values into columns, but I am not familiar on how to insert rows within a patch like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into photoProcessStory (processId, storyId)
select processId, storyId
from photoProcess
where storyId <> 0 and storyId is not null
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Only thing is it should be photoProcessStory, not photoProcessHistory.

Comment: @jmchauv please tick this as right answer if in fact it is.

Comment: @khaledOuertani I am as soon as stackoverflow lets me. You have to wait a certain amount of minutes before you can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

You can user `INSERT INTO.. SELECT`, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO photoProcessStory (processId, storyId)
SELECT processId, storyId FROM photoProcess WHERE storyId <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this just an `insert . . . select`?

```
insert into photoProcessStory(processId, storyId)
    select processId, storyId
    from photoProcess
    where storyId <> 0;
```